# MultiDimentional array in $_POST, checklist form

Tags: php, forms, post, multidimensional-array

I am trying to make a form that mocks a checklist of sorts. Let me explain:

I have a number of jars. Inside each jar are a number of jelly beans. Each bean is different. I can have any number of jars and beans. I want to create a form as so:

```
    public static function getForm($oData) {
        <form action="<?= esc_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); ?>" method="post" id="CountForm">
            <fieldset>

                <?php foreach ($aJars as $oJar) {
                    $aJellyBeans = JellyBeans::getJellyBeansBase($oJar->Jar_ID); ?>

                    <p><?= $oJar->JarName; ?></p>

                    <?php foreach ($aJellyBeans as $oJellyBean) { ?>

                        <input type="checkbox" name="?" id="CountedFor" value="1">

                        <input type="hidden" name="?" id="AccountedFor_ID" value="<?= $oData->AccountedFor_ID; ?>">

                        <input type="hidden" name="?" id="Jar_ID" value="<?= (($oData->Jar_ID) ? $oData->Jar_ID : $oJellyBean->Jar_ID); ?>">

                        <input type="hidden" name="?" id="JellyBean_ID" value="<?= (($oData->JellyBean_ID) ? $oData->JellyBean_ID : $oJellyBean->JellyBean_ID); ?>">

                        <label for="Notes">Notes</label>
                            <textarea name="?" id="Notes" cols="30" rows="5" wrap="soft" placeholder=" "><?= $oData->Notes; ?></textarea>
                    <?php } ?>

                <?php } ?>

                <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="<?= (($oData->AccountedFor_ID) ? 'Update' : 'Add' ) ?>">

            </fieldset>
            </form> <?php
    }
```

When $_POST gets sent it goes to a class function that handles writing to the DB. The function will look at the name field and use that as the column name.

```
    protected function CreateAccountedFor($aData) {
        //Process provided data
        foreach ($aData as $sKey => $eValue) {
            $aSQL[$sKey] = $eValue;
        }
    }
```

I want to create a list of each jelly bean, sorted by jar, and be able to check each off as "accounted for" and submitted in one go.

I know the name field is what $_POST looks at, but is there a way to manipulate that property to form an array like:

```
    ["AccountedFor"]=>
        [0]=>
           ["AccountedFor_ID"]=> "..."
           ["Jar_ID"]=> "..."
           ["JellyBean_ID"]=> "..."               
        [1]=>
           ["AccountedFor_ID"]=> "..."
           ["Jar_ID"]=> "..."
           ["JellyBean_ID"]=> "..."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the array values in the input name, use a for loop to count which iteration you're currently on.

If you're generating multiple of these inputs you're going to have invalid code, the id for each input will be repeated, maybe use classes instead or ditch them altogether.

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($aJellyBeans); $i++) { ?>

    <input type="checkbox" name="AccountedFor[$i][CountedFor]" id="CountedFor" value="1">

    <input type="hidden" name="AccountedFor[$i][AccountedFor_ID]" id="AccountedFor_ID" value="<?= $oData->AccountedFor_ID; ?>">

    <input type="hidden" name="AccountedFor[$i][Jar_ID]" id="Jar_ID" value="<?= (($oData->Jar_ID) ? $oData->Jar_ID : $aJellyBeans[$i]->Jar_ID); ?>">

    <input type="hidden" name="AccountedFor[$i][JellyBean_ID]" id="JellyBean_ID" value="<?= (($oData->JellyBean_ID) ? $oData->JellyBean_ID : $aJellyBeans[$i]->JellyBean_ID); ?>">

    <label for="Notes">Notes</label>
        <textarea name="?" id="Notes" cols="30" rows="5" wrap="soft" placeholder=" "><?= $oData->Notes; ?></textarea>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Ok I'll try this approach. I can even use `foreach ($aJellyBeans as $nKey => $oJellyBean)` and use the key value. I don't foresee myself using the id really, that was a coding habit I picked up. Unless another solution comes, this is my answer.